# UITableViewCell label resizes when I scroll

Tags: uitableview

I'm trying to create a standings table with a UITableView.

I've created a custom cell, with 7 labels. I have used grouped cells to differentiate between AL Central, NL East, etc.

Check out this image, when I load the view:

[image: View 1]

Compare that with the image when I scroll the view:
[image: View 2]

Here is my code (removed the repeated code):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                    }// end



    //rank
    UILabel *rank = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    //team
    UILabel *team = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];



    if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {

        NSArray *division = @[@"AL Central", @"AL East", @"AL West", @"NL Central", @"NL East", @"NL West"];


            rank.text = @"";
            team.text = division[indexPath.section];

            cell.backgroundColor = textPrimary;
            team.textColor = backgroundPrimary;

            team.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:5.0f];
            won.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f];

            return cell;

        }



    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    rank.textColor = textPrimary;
    team.textColor = textPrimary;

    int new_row = indexPath.row + indexPath.section*5 - 1;

    rank.text = [[[dataSource objectAtIndex:new_row] objectForKey:@"rank"] stringValue];
    team.text = [[dataSource objectAtIndex:new_row] objectForKey:@"first_name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the font again when it wasn't the header:

```
        team.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:5.0f];
```